# Uncaught type error: Object[object Object ] has no method 'tabs'

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to make tabs int the web browser. I have included all necessary .js files. I am still getting this error:

`$("#tabb").tabs();` where tabb is the div id.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs'`

I have attached all the .js files with it.

`jquery.js` , `jquery-ui.js (complete)` , `jquery-ui-tabs` (only the tab widget) still there is an error...

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

1.Check the jquery version that is getting loaded.
Olders versions will not have have functions like tabs.

2.Sometimes this issue will also arise if you have loaded multiple jquery.
The last jquery loaded will be looked for the same.

This error occurs often. Though the issue in the question was different.
The above two issues are the most common ones as I have found.

Comment: This solved my issue, I had two script tags loading jquery (with same version) but the last overwrited the added ui functions.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your code is executed after *jQuery UI* loading?
You should make sure DOM is ready, and wrap it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabb").tabs();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, for sure the `jQueryUI` is loaded as the `UI` code before is running flawlessly. The DOM is ready thats why the initial jQuery-UI has no issues.
I have tried your solution, but no tabs on web browser :(

Comment: So please provide a live example (maybe on jsfiddle.net)

Comment: <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 300px" src="http://jsfiddle.net/7m2dZ/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: Solved... the `.tab() function` was not supported in many of the jqueryui.js file. among many `version 1.8.22` worked and did the job for me. Hope it will work for you guys as well!!

Comment: I have this same problem but will this even affect anything? Or should I revert to 1.8.22?